# Unwanted /null image request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

Since a long time, in my React web project I have a strange request present in the log.

This is not a request that I sent, the origin is not my source code. The web browser point, as the source the error, the first line of my only .html file.

I have no clue to solve this error, and I really need to fix because there is a Fail to ban in the server-side.

Here some screenshot:
[image: Chrome network tool]
[image: Chrome console]

I hope someone can help me, I can give npm module list (with version) if needed.

Comment: There might be a null image requested as background style or something in a CSS. Isn't it?

Comment: you need to start debugging the script , you can find useful information in those logs and more useful information if you setup breakpoints and follow the execution step by step, it might be an third party script but I doubt it is.

Comment: I forgot to add: it's only append after a refresh of the page. I tried breakpoint, but it's transpilied source code, it doesn't help :(.

Comment: You can debug transpiled source code if you tell the transpiler to use source maps.

Comment: @ManishJangir it was style, but style write in js, depending on a props (that is not required).